# NestJS guard with GraphQL

Tags: nestjs

I am trying to add an auth guard to a GraphQL resolver but it doesn't seem to be working as expected.

I have a simple guard that should reject all requests:

```
@Injectable()
export class AuthGuard implements CanActivate {
  canActivate(context: ExecutionContext): boolean {
    return false;
  }
}
```

and have applied it in a resolver:

```
@Resolver()
export class RecipeResolver {
  
  @Query(() => [Recipe])
  @UseGuards(AuthGuard)
  public recipes(): Recipe[] {
    return this.recipeData;
  }
}
```

This does not work in the resolver and the `canActivate` is never fired.  This does work in an HTTP Controller.

Changing `@UseGuards(AuthGuard)` to `@UseGuards(new AuthGuard())` works but will not go through the dependency injection process which is not ideal.

What am I doing wrong?

Edit:

original `app.module.ts`:

```
@Module({
  imports: [
    GraphQLModule.forRoot({
      autoSchemaFile: 'shcema.gql',
      playground: true,
    }),
    RecipeResolver,
  ],
  controllers: [AppController],
  providers: [AppService],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Comment: From what you've shown, I don't see anything wrong. It looks fine to me

Comment: @JayMcDoniel I added a link to a github repo that shows the issue I am running into

Comment: Why is your `RecipeResolver` in the `AppModule`'s `imports` array? It should be in the `providers`

Comment: @JayMcDoniel moving it from `imports` to `providers` fixed the issue.  Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the code, the resolver was in the wrong location (in an `imports` array instead of `providers`) which meant Nest didn't set up the request lifecycle properly.